# Creating Vector Tile Package from basemap with ArcPy gives ERROR 001856: Cached scale doesn't match tiling scheme

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, vector-tile-package

I am trying to create a vector tile package from a basemap with arcpy, but get the using arcpy.management.CreateVectorTilePackage() causes me an error:

> ERROR 001856: Cached scale doesn't match tiling scheme.

My code is this:

```
import os

import arcpy

#set environment settings
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

outputPath = "C://PROYECTOS//Pruebas_para_paquetes//Paquetes//"

minscale = 295828763

maxscale = 564

#   create a vector tile package,
#   using the same name as the map
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("C://PROYECTOS//Pruebas_para_paquetes//Datos_Prueba_Portal_ICA//Datos_Prueba//Mapas_ICA//Mapas_ICA.aprx")
map = aprx.listMaps()[3]

indices = r"C:\PROYECTOS\Pruebas_para_paquetes\Datos_Prueba_Portal_ICA\Datos_Prueba\Mapas_ICA\Mapas_ICA.gdb\Indices"

print("Packaging " + map.name)

arcpy.management.CreateVectorTilePackage(map, 
                                        outputPath +'test.vtpk', 
                                        "ONLINE", 
                                        None, 
                                        "INDEXED", 
                                        minscale, 
                                        maxscale, 
                                        indices, 
                                        "Mapa Base", 
                                        "Mapa Base")
```

Comment: The error still persists,
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 001856: Cached scale doesn't match tiling scheme.
Failed to execute (CreateVectorTilePackage).

Comment: The map is in an arcGIS pro project, where i get the list of maps with their layers from the arpx file, and from there i have to create a vtpk file, but when i pass the me and execute parameters, i get an error. With the intefaces of arcGIS pro it generates without problems, but i need you to generate it with the python script

Comment: Here is the documentation, but this has not worked for me: https://pro.arcgis.com/es/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-vector-tile-package.htm

Comment: Dont think it matters but indices should be a feature layer accourding to the documentation, you are passing a feature class. Try creating a feature layer from the feature class using MakeFeatureLayer then use this as indices.'

Comment: In no way have i been able  to run the function for create Vector Tile package

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
arcpy.management.CreateVectorTilePackage(map, 
                                        outputPath +'test.vtpk', 
                                        "ONLINE", 
                                        None, 
                                        "INDEXED", 
                                        295828763.795777, 
                                        564.248588, 
                                        indices, 
                                        "Mapa Base", 
                                        "Mapa Base")
```

You have integers where the function is expecting floats for min & max scale.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a vtpk where the service type = True ( not "ONLINE" I guess ), the SRID of the map layer you're using has to be web mercator.  Open your file, select the map you're referencing, and change the project properties of the source map to be 3857 Web Mercator Aux Sphere.